# Как посчитать количество бит в одном байте на ассемблере?

Tags: битовые-операции, ассемблер

Здравствуйте.

Никак не могу додумать, как посчитать количество бит в одном байте, используя битовую маску и логические операции AND, OR, XOR, NOT.
Пишу на эмуляторе 8086.

Что такое битовая маска, я знаю, когда мы можем определенные биты числа сделать нулями или единицами, при этом другие биты оставить нетронутыми. Но как, используя маску, можно посчитать количество единиц в числе, состоящем из 8 бит (к примеру, 00011001)?

Comment: Например, так:

    mov eax, 8

(или `movl $8, %eax`, в зависимости от ассемблера)

Comment: Немного не пойму, указанная вами строка, записывает в регистр число 8, но как собственно происходит подсчет ?

Если к примеру имеется в регистре AL значение 00011001:
mov al, 00011001b

Comment: @walik: Ну, в байте 8 бит. Если вам нужны _только единичные_ биты, то вам сначала нужно выбрать какой-нибудь [алгоритм](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive).

Если ы увс достаточно новый процессор, подойдёт инструкция [`POPCNT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT).

Comment: Вот [алгоритм с масками (`NumberOfSetBits()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/109025).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@walik](/users/11852/walik)](/users/11852/walik), наверное, очевидней всего будет такой алгоритм:

```
Установим какой-нибудь регистр в 0xff (т.е. его младший байт будет содержать только единицы) и будем сдвигать его в цикле вправо, пока он не станет нулем. Подсчитаем число итераций и добавим к ним 1.
```

Теперь по поводу ассемблера. На мой взгляд, поучиться у оптимизирующего компилятора не самая плохая идея, особенно если Вы хоть немного знаете C.

Напишем простую функцию, реализующую наш алгоритм. Для того, чтобы компилятор не вычислил ответ (да, если информации достаточно, то он сделает это и лишит нас ассемблерного кода), передадим ему заполненный регистр через аргумент функции.

Вот сишный код нашей функции:

```
int nbits (int m) {
  int n = 0;

  while (m >>= 1)
    n++;

  return n + 1;
}
```

Вызовем компилятор для получения ее оптимизированного ассемблерного кода: `gcc -S -O3 nbits.c`
и получим в файле nbits.s вот такой текст:

```
        .file   "nbits.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
        .globl  nbits
        .type   nbits, @function
nbits:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        sarl    %edi
        je      .L5
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        addl    $1, %eax
        sarl    %edi
        jne     .L4
        addl    $1, %eax
        ret
.L5:
        movl    $1, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   nbits, .-nbits
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Вызывающая программа передает в `nbits()` один аргумент в регистре `edi`. Интересующий нас результат возвращается в регистре `eax`.

Поскольку Вы изучаете ассемблер, то, думаю, сами выудите оттуда и приведет к нужному виду относящийся к делу цикл.

Вызывающий `main` очевиден:

```
// file c.c: prints byte size using external function 
int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  return printf ("byte size: %d\n", nbits(0xff)) == EOF;
}
```

Теперь соберем все вместе и посмотрим на результат:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c.c nbits.s -O3
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
byte size: 8
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ uname -a
Linux avp-ubu1 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Answer (score 1):

Если надо посчитать биты в байте, проще всего использовать lookup-таблицу:

```
mov ebx, table
xlat

; ...
table db 0    ; 0000 0000
      db 1    ; 0000 0001
      db 1    ; 0000 0010
      db 2    ; 0000 0011
; и т. д.
```

Answer (score 0):

Короче говоря, не нашел толком, как это сделать, поэтому чтобы соответствовать условиям задачи (использовать логические операции и битовую маску), я просто перебирал каждый бит по отдельности и сравнивал его:

```
mov cx, 0
mov ax, 00011001b

mov bx, ax ;сохраняем в BX наше число
and bx, 00000001b ;Аннулируем все биты кроме первого
jz label1 ;Если первый бит тоже был нулем, то результатом станет ноль, значит флаг ZF будет равен одному и мы перепрыгнем след. инструкцию, если же бит был единицей, то инкрементируем регистр CX.
inc cx

label1: ;То же самое, только уже со вторым битом
mov bx, ax
and bx, 00000010b
jz label2
inc cx

label2:
mov bx, ax
and bx, 00000100b
jz label3
inc cx

label3: 
mov bx, ax
and bx, 00001000b
jz label4
inc cx

label4:
mov bx, ax
and bx, 00010000b
jz label5
inc cx

label5:
mov bx, ax
and bx, 00100000b
jz label6
inc cx

label6: 
mov bx, ax
and bx, 01000000b
jz label7
inc cx

label7:
mov bx, ax
and bx, 10000000b
jz label8
inc cx

label8:
```

В регистре CX в итоге хранится цифра, которая соответствует количеству единиц в байте.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть следует посчитать количество бит в регистре al, результат поместим в ecx, тогда:

```
       xor ecx, ecx
_loop:
       shr al, 1
       adc ecx, 0
       test al, al
       jnz _loop

; ecx = количество бит в al
```

Вот и всё.

walik, обратите внимания на инструкцию *test*. Она воздействует на флаги точно так же как и инструкция *and*, однако не записывает результат вычислений в регистр-приёмник. Поэтому и "восстанавливать" каждый раз значение регистра не нужно, а *jz* и другие условные переходы будут работать корректно.

Есть ещё одно решение, оно необычное и не использует вообще никаких условных переходов:

```
; подсчитываем количество бит в регистре al
; результат будет также содержаться в этом же регистре (al)
; регистр cl используем для хранения промежуточных результатов
mov cl, al
and cl, 0x55
shr al, 1
and al, 0x55
add al, cl
;------
mov cl, al
and cl, 0x33
shr al, 2
and al, 0x33
add al, cl
;------
mov cl, al
and cl, 0x0F
shr al, 4
and al, 0x0F
add al, cl
; на данном этапе al = искомое количество бит
```

Код корректен и не содержит ни одного условного перехода. Почему это работает описано в книге Генри Уоррен мл. "Алгоритмические трюки для программистов".